I can't apply button styling to the entire application
I have created a style to have a button with only a border using the material design 3 api. If I apply this style directly to the buttons the effect is the desired one but if I do a test so that it is applied in the activity or in the entire application so that affect all buttons then the style does not propagate. Any idea what's the problem here?
themes.xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/buttonOnlyBorder</item>
    </style>

</resources>

AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="28"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="buttonOnlyBorder" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="strokeColor">#DE0000</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Screenshot for styling on button directly
https://i.sstatic.net/GqmNPpQE.png
In this ask Applying buttonStyle via theme wouldn't work, applying directly works perfectly speak over similar situation but solution is not apply on my project.
https://i.sstatic.net/Inj4Q0Wk.png
Any idea, please??
